# Sum values from a map - elixir

Tags: elixir

I have managed to write code that appears to be working, but I don't know why.

Context: A project has many `budget_items`, these are preloaded with the project that I'm showing.

From the list of the `budget_items`, I'm calculating the full budget of the project as follows:

```rb
def total_budget(budget_items) do
  Enum.reduce(budget_items, fn item, acc ->
    %{amount_in_cents: item.amount_in_cents + acc.amount_in_cents}
    end)[:amount_in_cents]
    |> value_in_euro()
end

def value_in_euro(amount_in_cents) do
  amount_in_cents/100
  |> :erlang.float_to_binary([decimals: 2])
end
```

The result works, but I don't know what `acc` does and how this works in the end.

Can someone elaborate please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you let me re-write your code to make it just a bit more readable, it's equivalent to:

```rb
def total_budget(budget_items) do
  Enum.reduce(budget_items, fn item, acc ->
    %{amount_in_cents: item.amount_in_cents + acc.amount_in_cents}
  end)
  |> Map.get(:amount_in_cents)
  |> value_in_euro()
end
```

The important part for your question is the reduce block. If you take a look at [Enum.reduce/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.11.2/Enum.html#reduce/2), you'll see that:

> The first element of the enumerable is used as the initial value of the accumulator

A very simple way to understand how this works is with an example like this:

```rb
iex> l = [1, 2]
[1, 2]
iex> Enum.reduce(l, fn x, acc, -> IO.puts "X: #{x}; acc: #{acc}" end)
X: 2; acc: 1
:ok
```

from this, you can see that it pretty much starts from the second element, using the first element as the accumulator.

Therefore, when you pass in your `budget_items`, what happens is that it builds a map with the key `:amount_in_cents`, which to begin with, is equal to the sum of `amount_in_cents` from the first two items in your `budget_items`. And that map is passed along as your `acc` to the next iteration.

And for that next iteration (the third item), `acc` is  the map that got built in the first iteration, which only has the `:amount_in_cents` key, and again, it produces a map with only the `:amount_in_cents` key which will be equal to `amount_in_cents` from the third element plus the one in the accumulator, which is equal to the sum of the previous two. And it will be passed as the accumulator for the next iteration, and so on.

And then, when all of the `:amount_in_cents` from all items have been added, you get that value from the map that came out of the final iteration, and pass that along to `value_in_euro/1`.

So, in short, what `acc` does, is that it acts as an accumulator, keeping whatever you have been passing along from all previous iterations, so that you can use it however you need with each individual item from your enumerables. The result of the anonymous function passed to `Enum.reduce` will always be used as the accumulator for the next iteration, and the result from the final iteration is what will be "returned"

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the explanation of [`Enum.reduce/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3), in this case using a combination of [`Enum.map/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) and [`Enum.sum/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sum/1) is arguably simpler.

```
[
  %{amount_in_cents: 100},
  %{amount_in_cents: 200},
  %{amount_in_cents: 300}
]
|> Enum.map(fn item -> item.amount_in_cents end)
|> Enum.sum()
```

Output:

```
600
```

It's worth mentioning that `Enum.sum/1` [uses `Enum.reduce/3` internally](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.11.2/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L2817).